# Building the Bais Hamikdash Today

Tags: halacha, beis-hamikdash, modern-times

Why are there people who think there is no Mitzva to actively pursue Binyan Habayis (building the Temple) Vhakravas Korbanos (and offering sacrifices) Bzman Hazeh (in this time)? What are they relying upon?

Comment: I'm not aware of any such people. Citing that they exist would greatly improve this question.

Comment: Pikuach Nefesh seems the most obvious one.

Comment: @ShmuelBrin That's just a reason to not go about it like an idiot. Campaigning for greater access to the Temple Mount or other political initiatives with potential to eventually open up the area would still be obligatory. Right now the only place in the world you can get arrested for saying Pesukim under your breath is the Temple Mount. It's so absurd it would be funny if it wasn't true.

Comment: @DoubleAA Re your first comment: Do you know anyone who _does_ hold one should do so?

Comment: @Ypnypn You mean someone who thinks there is a Mitzva to actively pursue Binyan...Hazeh? I though everyone held that. Maybe Neturei Karta doesn't?

Comment: @ShmuelBrin Nissukh HaMayim doesn't. It won't even anger PETA. You got to think outside the box.

Comment: @DoubleAA [Glick's Son 'Prayed for His Father on Temple Mount'](http://www.israelnationalnews.com/News/News.aspx/186955#.VFeCFL9daK1).

Comment: judah simon, welcome to Mi Yodeya, and thanks very much for sharing this provocative question! I hope you'll look around and find other content of interest, perhaps including our 100+ other [tag:beis-hamikdash] questions.

Comment: @Scimonster Sorry, you're correct. Right now the only place in the world you need to have your father almost assassinated in order to gain the right to not be arrested for saying Pesukim under your breath is the Temple Mount.

Answer (score 2):

For a start, where would you build the Mizbeach?

The Rambam in [הלכות בית הבחירה - פרק שני](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_02001.html#HtmpReportNum0001_L2) says it has to be exactly in its correct place, and has to be of precise measurements.

Since we don't have a prophet to show us where to build the Mizbeach, why would we bother?

> **א** **הַמִּזְבֵחַ מְקוֹמוֹ מְכֻוָּן בְּיוֹתֵר. וְאֵין מְשַׁנִּין אוֹתוֹ מִמְּקוֹמוֹ לְעוֹלָם**. שֶׁנֶּאֱמַר (דברי הימים א כב-א) 'זֶה מִזְבַּח לְעוֹלָה לְיִשְׂרָאֵל'. וּבַמִּקְדָּשׁ נֶעֱקַד יִצְחָק אָבִינוּ שֶׁנֶּאֱמַר (בראשית כב-ב) 'וְלֶךְ לְךָ אֶל אֶרֶץ הַמֹּרִיָּה'. וְנֶאֱמַר בְּדִבְרֵי הַיָּמִים (דברי הימים ב ג-א) 'וַיָּחֶל שְׁלֹמֹה לִבְנוֹת אֶת בֵּית ה' בִּירוּשָׁלַיִם בְּהַר הַמּוֹרִיָּה אֲשֶׁר נִרְאָה לְדָוִיד אָבִיהוּ אֲשֶׁר הֵכִין בִּמְקוֹם דָּוִיד בְּגֹרֶן אָרְנָן הַיְבוּסִי':‏
>
> **ב** וּמָסֹרֶת בְּיַד הַכּל שֶׁהַמָּקוֹם שֶׁבָּנָה בּוֹ דָּוִד וּשְׁלֹמֹה הַמִּזְבֵּחַ בְּגֹרֶן אֲרַוְנָה הוּא הַמָּקוֹם שֶׁבָּנָה בּוֹ אַבְרָהָם הַמִּזְבֵּחַ וְעָקַד עָלָיו יִצְחָק. וְהוּא הַמָּקוֹם שֶׁבָּנָה בּוֹ נֹחַ כְּשֶׁיָּצָא מִן הַתֵּבָה. וְהוּא הַמִּזְבֵּחַ שֶׁהִקְרִיב עָלָיו קַיִן וְהֶבֶל. וּבוֹ הִקְרִיב אָדָם הָרִאשׁוֹן קָרְבָּן כְּשֶׁנִּבְרָא וּמִשָּׁם נִבְרָא. אָמְרוּ חֲכָמִים אָדָם מִמְּקוֹם כַּפָּרָתוֹ נִבְרָא:‏
>
> **ג** **מִדּוֹת הַמִּזְבֵּחַ מְכֻוָּנוֹת הַרְבֵּה וְצוּרָתוֹ יְדוּעָה אִישׁ מֵאִישׁ**. וּמִזְבֵּחַ שֶׁבָּנוּ בְּנֵי הַגּוֹלָה כְּעֵין מִזְבֵּחַ שֶׁעָתִיד לְהִבָּנוֹת עָשׂוּהוּ **וְאֵין לְהוֹסִיף עַל מִדָּתוֹ וְלֹא לִגְרֹעַ מִמֶּנָּה**:‏
>
> ד וּשְׁלֹשָׁה נְבִיאִים עָלוּ עִמָּהֶם מִן הַגּוֹלָה. **אֶחָד הֵעִיד לָהֶן עַל מְקוֹם הַמִּזְבֵּחַ.** וְאֶחָד הֵעִיד לָהֶן עַל מִדּוֹתָיו. וְאֶחָד הֵעִיד לָהֶן שֶׁמַּקְרִיבִין עַל הַמִּזְבֵּחַ הַזֶּה כָּל הַקָּרְבָּנוֹת אַף עַל פִּי שֶׁאֵין שָׁם בַּיִת:‏

Comment: Well, maybe we could still find out where it was if we could dig around there. Do you know otherwise? This doesn't answer the question which was whether or not we should be trying. You are just saying it may be difficult. Frankly, I think we already knew that.

Comment: If they needed a Navi for the 2nd - after 70 years, it's fair to assume you'd need one after ±2,000 years. Besides, how do you plan on digging around there? They barely allow you to breath up there, when they let you in. But back to the OP: "What are they relying upon?" They are relying on the lack of a Navi (to confirm any proofs they dig up).

Comment: First of all it doesn't say that you need a Navi, it only says they had a Navi. Second of all, the Navi didn't say a Nevua, he just testified that that was where it had been previously. Third of all, with our advanced archeological equipment, there is no good reason to assume that we wouldn't be able to find a spot big enough for the minimal shiur of a mizbeach.

Comment: @judahsimon Were those three neviim people who had been there when the First Temple was destroyed 70 years earlier?

Comment: @DannySchoemann Not fair. We have vastly better technology. And to the OP: Danny must be wrong because they can't be relying on something which doesn't answer the question.

Comment: According to the Temple Institute, a temporary *mizbei'ach* can be created that is not full size.

Comment: @Scimonster - I quoted my sources, I wonder what there's is.

Comment: I don't remember, it's been a couple years since i visited. Next time you're in Jerusalem, feel free to walk in and ask at the desk. :)

Answer (score 0):

Rav Mashash in [Otzar Hamichtavim 3:775](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=22016&st=&pgnum=172) holds that it is impossible to build the bais hamikdash today for many reasons.1) we dont know exactly where to build the bais hamikdash and especially the mizbeiach which even after the first destruction which lasted only 70 years still they needed neviem to tell them where to build it ,so especially after 2000 years kol shekain(like Danny Schoemann's answer). 2) The stones of the mizbeiach need to be perfectly smooth and its impossible unless we use the shamir(cant use metal to do it). 3) we dont have a kohen who is meychus all the way to Ahron Hakohen ,but rather a chezkas kohen. We are also all temei Maisem and we need a parah adumah. There are many more things as well,rather we wait and hope for Mashiach.

Comment: "We are also all temei Maisem and we need a parah adumah." That must be a typo, as the Halacha is clear that טומאה הותרה בציבור. "The stones of the mizbeiach need to be perfectly smooth and its impossible unless we use the shamir(cant use metal to do it)." That also must be a typo as the Rambam is clear that metal can be used in preparation done outside Har HaBayit. Plus we have enough technology nowadays to make plastics or lasers that can cut stone just fine, so no need for a Shamir. This "responsum" should probably be buried, being full of clear mistakes.

Comment: @doubleaa you wouldn't be the first to say that or prob last

Comment: @doubleaa one can understand this teshuva as saying that there are so many things that are problematic that it is almost impossible, the things you mentioned are bedieved cases and things which where once disputed